# How to derive the formula of the term in $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1\cdot4\cdot \ldots \cdot(3n+1)}{(2n+1)!!} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I stumbled upon the following exam problem

Test the convergence of the series:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1\cdot4\cdot \ldots \cdot(3n+1)}{(2n+1)!!} $$

So I figured every second factor of the numerator will cancel out with every factor in the denominator and that will give(actually not true)*

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty4\cdot10\cdot16\cdot22...$$

In this particular case it might already be obvious that the series diverge but I wanted to derive an exact formula so I can prove the convergence or divergence with proper criteria/test. And after spending 10 minutes of trying to figure it out, I came up with the following formula $\ 2(2+3(n+1))=6n-2$. What turns out to be pretty easy to discover in this particular case if I did notice that those numbers were multiples of 6 - 2.

My question is, is there a known way to derive these formulas from infinite sums and infinite products? Or the deriving process becomes more easier just with time and practice?

I'm  pretty new to all this stuff, sorry if I'm missing the obvious with the question.

*As pointed out by @alex.jordan in the comments, I made a mistake there and the cancellation won't happen in the way I described. Nevertheless, it doesn't affect the essence of the question, therefore I will leave it unedited for now.

Comment: Grigori! Shouldn't you be working on the RH right now? xD

Comment: Mr. Perelman, I believe it just becomes easier with time and practice. You pick up necessary tricks and methods along the way. Some of them are inspired from popular proofs of well-known results, but it's the familiarity and the grit to sit and write it out that takes you along. ...................... Having said that, @Riemann'sPointyNose , nobody tells Mr. Perelman what he should work on :3 he takes care of his mother, his backyard and his own exercises in his own flow. ;)

Comment: In the context of timed exams where these questions come out, trying to individually compute more than a few terms is misguided. Instead, when you see factorials or similar products, the best thing to do is usually to invoke the ratio test.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski That isn't what the double factorial notation means.  $5!!=5\cdot3\cdot1=15$;  $6!!=6\cdot4\cdot2$ and so forth

Comment: The ratio of consecutive terms is $(3n+1)/(2n+1)$.

Comment: Perelman won't struggle on test. Only people struggle on Perelman's text.

Comment: You can prove divergence with a "proper test" without find a closed formula. If you apply the Ratio Test with this series, you get $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{3n+4}{2n+3}$, whose limit is $\infty$. The Ratio Test therefore tells you the original series diverges.

Comment: "I figured every second factor of the numerator will cancel out with every factor in the denominator". I do not follow this. For example the $n=2$ term is $\frac{1\cdot4\cdot7}{5\cdot3\cdot1}$. Where is that cancellation?

Comment: @alex.jordan You are right, I made a mistake there, thanks. There is actually no cancellation in the way I described it. It turns out only every 3rd factor in the denominator will cancel out, but the numerator will keep growing faster and faster as n increases.

Comment: @alex.jordan considering your other answer where you suggested the usage of the Ratio Test; what did you take for $a_n$ and why ? $a_n=2n+3$ ?

Comment: I'm not saying $a_n$ is $2n+3$. I'm saying if you look at the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ lots of factors cancel and you are left with $\frac{3n+4}{2n+3}$.

Comment: @alex.jordan I see, but what do you consider as $a_n$ in that case ? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I posted an answer. Also in a comment here, I said "whose limit is $\infty$" which was a silly mistake. Of course that limit is $\frac{3}{2}$. But the point is, it's larger than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning a comment thread into an answer:

Without explicitly finding a closed formula for the terms, you can still apply the Ratio Test. All terms are positive, so I will omit using absolute value that is in the more general form of the Ratio Test.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
&=\frac{\frac{1\cdot4\cdot \ldots \cdot(3(n+1)+1)}{(2(n+1)+1)!!}}{\frac{1\cdot4\cdot \ldots \cdot(3n+1)}{(2n+1)!!}}\\
&=\frac{1\cdot4\cdot \ldots \cdot(3(n+1)+1)}{1\cdot4\cdot \ldots \cdot(3n+1)}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2(n+1)+1)!!}\\
&=\frac{\require{cancel}\cancel{1\cdot4\cdot \ldots \cdot(3n+1)}\cdot(3(n+1)+1)}{\cancel{1\cdot4\cdot \ldots \cdot(3n+1)}}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+3)!!}\\
&=(3n+4)\cdot\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+3)\cdot(2n+1)!!}\\
&=\frac{3n+4}{2n+3}
\end{align}
$$

This expression goes to $\frac{3}{2}>1$ as $n\to\infty$, so by the Ratio Test, the original series diverges.

Comment: Many thanks. Even this answer isn’t answering the original question, I marked it as correct due to lack of a better answer and because the author contributed in several ways to other concerns of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$a_n=\frac{\prod_{k=0}^n (3k+1) } {(2n+1)!! }\qquad \text{and} \qquad S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n$$ The first $S_p$'s are easy to compute; they generate the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{4}{3},\frac{16}{5},\frac{88}{15},\frac{1312}{135},\frac{2528}{165},\frac
   {34912}{1485},\frac{31648}{891},\frac{89504}{1683},\frac{1199776}{15147},\frac{5345248}{45441}\right\}$$ which is "almost" exponential.

**Edit**

Sooner or later, you will learn that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,x^n=\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{4}{3};\frac{3}{2};\frac{3 }{2}x\right)$$ which is the gaussian hypergeometric function which tends to $\infty$ when $x\to \frac 23$ from below.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{1\times 4 \times \cdots \times
\pars{3n + 1} \over \pars{2n + 1}!!}} =
{\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{3k + 1} \over
\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{2k + 1}} =
{3^{n + 1}\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{k + 1/3} \over
2^{n + 1}\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{k + 1/2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{3 \over 2}^{n + 1}\,
{\pars{1/3}^{\overline{n + 1}} \over
\pars{1/2}^{\overline{n + 1}}} =
\pars{3 \over 2}^{n + 1}\,
{\Gamma\pars{n + 4/3}/\Gamma\pars{1/3} \over
\Gamma\pars{n + 3/2}/\Gamma\pars{1/2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\root{\pi} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3}}\pars{3 \over 2}^{n + 1}\,
{\pars{n + 1/3}! \over \pars{n + 1/2}!}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\, &
{\root{\pi} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3}}\pars{3 \over 2}^{n + 1}\,
{\root{2\pi}\pars{n + 1/3}^{\ n + 5/6}\expo{-n - 1/3} \over
\root{2\pi}\pars{n + 1/2}^{\ n + 1}\expo{-n - 1/2}}
\\[5mm]  \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\, &\
{\root{\pi} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3}}\pars{3 \over 2}^{n + 1}\,
{n^{n + 5/6}\,\bracks{1 + \pars{1/3}/n}^{\ n}\,\expo{-n - 1/3} \over
n^{n + 1}\,\bracks{1 + \pars{1/2}/n}^{\ n}\,\expo{-n - 1/2}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\, &
{\root{\pi} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3}}\,
{\pars{3/2}^{n + 1} \over n^{1/6}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,
\bbx{\large \infty} \\ &
\end{align}